# What sets are these pieces from, rock platforms and walls with large cannons

Tags: piece-information, clone-brands

I think I have a couple of sets I'm trying to put together for my son that were my brother's when he was young. Probably from around year 2010 or earlier. Looks like a black castle or dungeon. Also with gargoyles and broken wire cells. Also have large rock platforms and rock walls. Please help. I've searched and can't even find the pieces online.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have some Mega Bloks sets.

I can't say for sure if these are sets you have, but I found similar pieces in these sets:

**[Dragons Battle Gate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067PFR)**

[image: Dragons Battle Gate Picture]

**[Portal of Fire](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001NEA1Q)**

[image: Portal of Fire Picture]

I don't know of any resources for non-LEGO instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Red cannons from second foto from mega bloks pirates: [Shark escape](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/3692.pdf), [Plunderer's port](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/3634.pdf). Gold cannon was in many sets: [Mutiny isle](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/3632.pdf), [Captain cutlass' stormstalker](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/3620.pdf), [Port royal](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/1016.pdf)…

More dragon sets: [Tower](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9896.pdf), [Warriors fortress](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9890.pdf), [Sorcerer's lair](https://support.megabrands.com/media/playbooks/9886.pdf).